# How does WordPress know wich language is chosen when there is a database connection error

Tags: php, database

When I have a db connection error in WordPress, WordPress shows the following error:

> Error establishing a database connection

But when my website's language is set to german, the message shows:

> Fehler beim Aufbau einer Datenbankverbindung

Which is basically the same error message but in german. But how does WP know which language is chosen, since it could not connect to the database server?

Comment: Do you mean the same website in different language or 2 different WP installs?

Comment: Maybe you got `WPLANG` defined in the `wp-config.php` file or somewhere?

Comment: @gael Sorry didn't get your question
@SallyCJ no I can't find `WPLANG` defined anywhere. I deleted the cache, and cleared the browser cache. But nothing seems to change.

Comment: @gael I just understood what you said, and found out that `$wp_local_package = 'de_DE';` was hardcoded in `wp-includes/version.php`